# calculating the mean of columns in text files

Tags: awk

I have two folders named f1 and f2. These folders contain 300 text files with 2 columns.The content of files are shown below.I would like to calculate the mean of second column.file names are same in both folders.

```
file1 in f1 folder
54  6
55 10
57 5

file2 in f1 folder
24  8
28  12

file1 in f2 folder
34 3
22 8

file2 in f2 folder
24  8
28  13
```

output

```
                   folder1       folder2

     file1         21/3= 7       11/2=5.5
     file2         20/2=10       21/2=10.5

      --            --             --    

      --            --             --

    file300         --             --

              total mean of folder1 = sum of the means/3oo
              total mean of folder2 = sum of the means/3oo
```

Comment: Are there any files in folder1 that don't appear in folder2 or vice versa?  What arguments do you see being passed on the command line?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The no:of files are same in folder1 and folder2.. I will check this to my needs in a few hours and then accept your answer.

Comment: OK, but note that if you have files `f1/n1`, `f1/n2`, `f2/n1` and `f2/n3`, the number of files in the two folders are the same, but there's a file in `f1` (namely `n2`) with no counterpart in `f2`, and a file in `f2` (namely `n3`) with no counterpart in `f1`.  So I was asking about a stronger condition than 'is the number of files the same'.  However, the code will bomb out with a divide by zero error if there's a file present in one that's missing from the other.  It could be made proof against such a failure, but you've said it won't happen.  (My answer code also works on 3 directories.)

Comment: @leffler The number and name of files are same in all folders. Can I use this code for more than three directories? I tried like this awk -f summary1.awk  f1/*.txt,f2/*.txt,f3/*.txt,f4/*.txt,f5/*.txt  | awk -f summary2.awk .But I get error. awk: cannot open f1/*.txt,f2/*.txt,f3/*.txt,f4/*.txt,f5/*.txt  (No such file or directory).  I would like to change the formula of total mean as you wrote. That was a mistake.

Comment: The code is not limited to 2 or 3 directories; it will nominally cope with 5 or even 50 directories. The output format would be very wide, but that is a presentational rather than computational issue.  Your problem on the command line came from using commas rather than spaces to separate the file names: `awk -f summary1.awk f1/*.txt f2/*.txt f3/*.txt f4/*.txt f5/*.txt | awk -f summary2.awk` should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Code works well. How can I reduce the space between columns in the output?

Comment: One big space consumer is the 20 spaces reserved for file names; if you know how long your file names are, you reduce that, perhaps dramatically. The other big space consumer are the numbers being printed. I gave 3 dp for the average, and allow for 6 digits before the decimal point. If you only need one or two dp, you can change `%10.3f` to `%8.1f`; if you know the numbers are going to be under 1000, you can shrink that to `%5.1f` or `%6.2f`. Similarly with the sums and counts; I allowed for 6 digit sums and 3 digit counts; reduce those to suit. Also reduce the extra spaces in the formats.

Comment: @Jonathan leffler I need one more help from you. How can I change the fomula for the total mean?

Comment: Replace `gsum[folder] += a` with `gsum[folder] += s; gcnt[folder] += n;` in the accumulation phase.  Then print the averages from `gsum` and `gcnt` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it with two `awk` scripts.  (Originally, I had a `sort` phase in the middle, but that isn't actually necessary.  However, I think that two scripts is probably easier than trying to combine them into one.  If someone else does it 'all in one' and it is comprehensible, then choose their solution instead.)

#### Sample run and output

This is based on the 4 files shown in the question.  The names of the files are listed on the command line, but the order doesn't matter.  The code assumes that there is only one slash in the file names, and no spaces and the like in the file names.

```
$ awk -f summary1.awk f?/* | awk -f summary2.awk
file1                      21/3   =      7.000       11/2   =      5.500
file2                      20/2   =     10.000       21/2   =     10.500
total mean of f1     =     17/2   =      8.500
total mean of f2     =     16/2   =      8.000
```

#### summary1.awk

```
function print_data(file, sum, count) {
    sub("/", " ", file);
    print file, sum, count;
}
oldfile != FILENAME { if (count > 0) { print_data(oldfile, sum, count); }
                      count = 0; sum = 0; oldfile = FILENAME
                    }
                    { count++; sum += $2 }
END                 { print_data(oldfile, sum, count) }
```

This processes each file in turn, summing the values in column 2 and counting the number of lines.  It prints out the folder name, the file name, the sum and the count.

#### summary2.awk

```
    {
        sum[$2,$1] = $3
        cnt[$2,$1] = $4
        if (file[$2]++ == 0) file_list[n1++] = $2
        if (fold[$1]++ == 0) fold_list[n2++] = $1
    }
END {   for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        { 
            printf("%-20s", file_list[i])
            name = file_list[i]
            for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            {
                folder = fold_list[j]
                s = sum[name,folder]
                n = cnt[name,folder]
                a = (s + 0.0) / n
                printf("   %6d/%-3d = %10.3f", s, n, a)
                gsum[folder] += a
            }
            printf("\n")
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        {
            folder = fold_list[i]
            s = gsum[folder]
            n = n1;
            a = (s + 0.0) / n
            printf("total mean of %-6s = %6d/%-3d = %10.3f\n", folder, s, n, a)
        }
    }
```

The `file` associative array tracks references to file names.  The `file_list` array keeps the file names in the order that they're read.  Similarly, the `fold` associative array tracks the folder names, and the `fold_list` array keeps track of the folder names in the order that they appear.  If you do something weird enough with the order that you supply the names to the first command, you may need to insert a `sort` command between the two `awk` commands, such as `sort -k2,2 -k1,1`.

The `sum` associative array contains the sum for a given file name and folder name.  The `cnt` associative array contains the count for a given file name and folder name.

The `END` section of the report has two main loops (though the first loop contains a nested loop).  The first main loop processes the files in the order presented, generating one line containing one entry for each folder.  It also accumulates the averages for the folder name.
The second main loop generates the 'total mean` data for each folder.  I'm not sure whether the statistics makes sense (shouldn't the overall mean for folder1 be the sum of the values in folder1 divided by the number of entries, or 41/5 = 8.2 rather than 17/2 or 8.5?), but the calculation does what I think the question asks for (sum of means / number of files, written as 300 in the question).

Answer (score 0):

With some help from grep:

```
grep '[0-9]' folder[12]/* | awk '
    {
       split($0,b,":"); 
       f=b[1]; split(f,c,"/"); d=c[1]; f=c[2]; 
       s[f][d]+=$2; n[f][d]++; nn[d]++;} 
    END{ 
      for (f in s) {
        printf("%-10s", f);
        for (d in s[f]) {
          a=s[f][d] / n[f][d];
          printf(" %6.2f ", a);
          p[d] += a;
        }
        printf("\n");
      }  
      for (d in p) { 
        printf("total mean %-8s = %8.2f\n", d, p[d]/nn[d]);
      }
    }'
```